# For loop works perfectly fine, but once I make a function out of it, it suddenly doesn't give the right results in R

Tags: r, function, loops

I have the following for-loop which does exactly what I want:

```
for (t in 3:20){
    XX <- c(rep(0,22))

    for (k in (1:(t-2))){

        XX[k] <- (theta^(k-1) * (P[t-k] - P[t-k-1]))
                }
        X[t] = (1-theta)  * sum(XX) + theta^(t-1)
        P[t] <- D[t] + (0.7/0.3) * X[t] - 0.1*3^2*1*(20-t-1 + (1/0.3))  
            }
```

However, once I make a function out of and use the function the results are suddenly wrong:

```
BGJS <- function(theta){

for (t in 3:20){
    XX <- c(rep(0,22))

    for (k in (1:(t-2))){

        XX[k] <- (theta^(k-1) * (P[t-k] - P[t-k-1]))
                }
        X[t] = (1-theta)  * sum(XX) + theta^(t-1)
        P[t] <- D[t] + (0.7/0.3) * X[t] - 0.1*3^2*1*(20-t-1 + (1/0.3))  
            } 
    }
```

Can someone find the mistake?

Comment: First thing you should correct your indentation!

Comment: To help us help you: What is an example input and desired output? What is right versus wrong? From a first pass, you are only feeding theta into your function. Are P and P globe? You also have a `X[t] =` instead of a `X[t] <-` but I can't tell if that was intentional on your part.

Comment: @user10488504 thank you very much! This is the answer I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `<-` and `=` to `<<-` as your scope is different in functions.

`?"<<-"`

The operators `<-` and `=` assign into the environment in which they are evaluated. ...

The operators `<<-` and `->>` are normally only used in functions, and cause a search to be made through parent environments for an existing definition of the variable being assigned. ...

Comment: Could you explain when to use each of the operators?