# R: How can I append multiple rows to a data.frame during a loop?

Tags: r

I discovered that it seems that I can not add rows to a data.frame in place.

The following code is a minimal example which should append a new row to the data.frame every iteration, but it does not append any.

Please note, in reality I have a complex for-loop with a lot of different if-statements and depending on them I want to append new different data to different data frames.

```
df <- data.frame(value=numeric()) 

appendRows <- function(n_rows) {
  for(i in 1:n_rows) {
    print(i)
    df <- rbind(df, setNames(i,names(df)))
  }
}
appendRows(10) #Does not append any row, whereas "df <- rbind(df, setNames(1,names(df)))" in a single call appends one row.
```

How can rows be added to a data.frame in place?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Change to `df <<- rbind(df, setNames(i,names(df)))`. (see Scope)

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56634717/10488504

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R function not returning values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570176/r-function-not-returning-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to return your object:

```
df <- data.frame(value=numeric())

appendRows <- function(n_rows) {
  for(i in 1:n_rows) {
    print(i)
    df <- rbind(df, setNames(i,names(df)))
  }
  return(df)
}
appendRows(10)
```

To modify `df` you have to store it:

```
df <- appendRows(10)
```